# How to pass additional information to a callback of a 3rd party module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

It is a simple node.js application. I'm using `Browser.visit(url, callback)` provided by Zombie module (http://zombie.labnotes.org), `Browser.visit()` will call the callback as `(error, browser, status)` in uncertain future with different context. And my callback need some extra information to finish its job.

So far I can make it "working" as:

```
function test(title, url) {
    var browser = new Browser();
    browser.visit(url, function (e, browser, status, thetitle) 
    {
         // generate info using the title if browser visited url successfully
    }
    .bind(undefined, browser, undefined, title);
}

test("foo", fooUrl);
test("bar", barUrl);
```

But there is a problem, the `bind()` just bypassed the error and status parameters. It seems not the right way. How could I pass the additional info to this callback?

FYI: Just got confirmed, the API doc of Zombie.js is for 1.4.x, 2.0.0-Alpha API is not finalized yet. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/zombie-js/qOS0W_cMCgQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand your question, I'm not sure why you are using `bind`, but perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve?

Javascript

```
function Browser(url) {
    this.url = url;
}

Browser.prototype.visit = function (url, fn) {
    var self = this,
        error = 'error',
        status = 'status';

    setTimeout(function () {
        fn(error, self, status);
    }, 1000);
};

function test(title, url) {
    var browser = new Browser(url);

    browser.visit(url, (function (theTitle) {
        return function (theError, theBrowser, theStatus) {
            // generate info using the title if browser visited url successfully
            console.log('theError: ', theError);
            console.log('theBrowser: ', theBrowser);
            console.log('theStatus: ', theStatus);
            console.log('theTitle: ', theTitle);
        };
    }(title)));
}

test('hello', 'world');
test('goodbye', 'mum');
```

Output

```
theError:  error
theBrowser:  Browser {url: "world", visit: function}
theStatus:  status
theTitle:  hello

theError:  error
theBrowser:  Browser {url: "mum", visit: function}
theStatus:  status
theTitle:  goodbye
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/vszTF/)

Comment: I just add the link to Zombie.js module. You are almost there, except visit will call fn as fn(error, this, status), all these 3 parameters are important for the callback.

Comment: I've updated my answer, although I'm still unclear as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, as I have mentioned I'm using node.js, when my callback is called, it is async running in not-the-same context, which means title parameter of test() is no longer available for access.

Comment: In my case, the context of calling Browser.visit() is different than   the one invoking the fn/callback because Browser invokes it when some event appears but the visit() call returns immediately. Sorry it is my bad not to explain more details about node.js background and thanks for the information anyway.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean without you providing some further code example of your problem. But updated again showing the `title` captured locally to the function that you are providing to `visit`

Comment: you are right, wrapping in a closure works. I got some misunderstanding or misleading on Zombie.js API, the value of callback parameters are undefined instead of those described in API doc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `bind` just to make the anonymous function passed to `browser.visit` access `title`. This would work:

```
function test(title, url) {
    var browser = new Browser();
    browser.visit(url, function (e, browser, status) {
        console.log(title);
    });
}
```

The value of `title` in `console.log(title)` is the same as the value of the `title` parameter of the `test` function.

Note that this works whether the callback passed to `browser.visit` is called synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: This was an example that I demonstrated previously, and believed would work also, but the OP is saying that it doesn't?

Comment: It is my first version indeed, but it is not right here. If I call test() multiple times, title will be always the last one.

Comment: That should not be the case with the latest example that I have given.

Comment: @pinxue Either you are not testing the code correctly or there is something you have failed to tell us in your question. Because if what your question shows is complete then using `bind` like you show in your question would suffer from the *exact same problem* you claim my answer suffers from.

Comment: As I said, this would seem to work for me too and was my first suggestion, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/a68GU/). There has to be some information that we are missing.

Comment: @Xotic750 Yes, something is missing.